# C# confirm() Function Browser Refresh Issue

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c# program, that uses the JavaScript confirm() function to create a yes/no alert.

The issue that I'm having is:

1. I click "yes" on the pop-up and the program executes.
2. Now, when I refresh the browser, a "confirm form re-submission" message appears, and if I click on "continue" the same yes/non pop-up appears again, instead of reloading the page. And I'm forced to select a yes or no again.

[Confirm Re-Submission PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMowZ.png)

JavaScript:

```
function Confirm()
        {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?"))
            {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
```

C#:

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
                    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                    {
                        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You selected yes.')", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You selected no.')", true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exceptionLabel.Text = (ex.Message);
                }           
        }
```

Comment: Is the Confirm() method being executed when submitting the form? If so you might want to hook into the onclick event instead of onsubmit!

Comment: The Confirm() is being called on the "OnClientClick event

Comment: Can you share the form element that is seen on the browser when the html page is loaded?

Comment: Are you asking for a screenshot of the webpage

This is the form element: -

<asp:Button ID="resetPwdButton" runat="server" OnClientClick = "Confirm()" BackColor="#003300" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="White" OnClick="OnConfirm" style="z-index: 1; left: 725px; top: 299px; position: absolute; width: 220px; height: 34px" />

Comment: Have you tried setting `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on the Button?

Comment: @Sahil - No. When the ASPX page is loaded in the browser, view its source to find the form element.
At the end of the day, everything that is placed on the aspx page gets converted to plain html + javascript. Investigating the transformed html/javascript will allow you to find the root cause and then you can look for the solution.

Comment: Mt. Schneiders - Yeah, I tried that, but that didn't help